# WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not working on lollipop even though it's set in the manifest

Tags: android, permissions, android-external-storage

I'm trying to save images from the apps local data folders to external storage. My manifest contains the following (before the manifest's application tags):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

When I try the following

```
try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        File outPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File outFile = new File(outPath, "mypicture.jpg");


        //try fails at this line
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/mypicture.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I've also tried a slightly different output path instead:

```
 String sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder";
 new File(sdCardPath).mkdirs();
 File outFile = new File(sdCardPath, "mypicture.jpg");
```

but that gives me an error too:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/mypicture.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The device is running Android 4.4.2, so shouldn't need to request permissions at runtime (as far as I'm aware it *can't* request them).

Is there something else that could be missing in order to allow saving a file to external storage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cause of the issue was an external library pulled in via gradle which had its own manifest requesting `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18">`

My own manifest only worked if maxSdkVersion="18" was NOT included, and so the manifest merger adding that param caused this error. My solution was to change my own manifest to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="23" tools:replace="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

I assume that the maxSdkVersion="18" meant that any devices running SDK 19-22 could not have this permission (with 23+ being able to request it at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

It shoudn't be necessary, but try to add this permission in you Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/>
```

Sometimes Android trolls us.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 6, you need to request permission at runtime. If you run on 4.4, still have that error, I think you have not create folder yet.

```
 String sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder";
 new File(sdCardPath) .mkdirs(); //create folders where write files
 File outFile = new File(sdCardPath, "mypicture.jpg");
```

Comment: I already have a line to create the folders as seen above: 
    new File(sdCardPath).mkdirs();
Which doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Oh. Srry my bag. Do you try to remove `android:maxSdkVersion="18"`. Or your directory is correct with your picture path `MyFolder\mypicture.jpg`?

Comment: I've tried both with and without maxSdkVersion, neither made a difference. I believe the path is correct, I've also tried putting mypicture.jpg directly into Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() but had the same error. It's almost as if the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission has not been granted on install, even though it is definitely in the manifest (I've used apktool to check it wasn't stripped out somehow).

Comment: I've just noticed something interesting. When I side load the app and it lists permissions that are needed, I don't see "modify or delete the contents of your SD card" and "read the contents of your SD card", which I do see when I install another app. This seems very strange since the permissions are clearly in the manifest, would something else be needed to make those permissions appear on install?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/MyFolder");    
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";

File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
file.createNewFile();
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

also add both read and write permission to the manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```