# Storage permission not given

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to give an Android app the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but it doesn't seem to be given the permission in the emulator. The Android.manifest looks like follows:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

As you can see, I've clearly `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Anyone know why the permission is still not given? I've tried various emulators (API 24, 26, 28).

Any thought appreciated.

EDIT: My project has quite a few dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-code-push": "^5.3.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.0",
    "react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "^5.6.3",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-photo-upload": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-ui-kitten": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
    "recyclerlistview": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-wheel-picker": "^2.0.0",
  },
```

Comment: What's the exact error message given please?

Comment: @Liam I don't see the 'Storage' permission under settings and I simply can't write to SD.

Comment: What about the other settings? I'm assuming they all show fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've fixed it with `PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)`.

Comment: In which file did you write this code? can you write the full code?

Comment: import {
  PermissionsAndroid
} from 'react-native';
PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" tools:replace="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

Taken from:
[WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not working on lollipop even though it's set in the manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552251/write-external-storage-not-working-on-lollipop-even-though-its-set-in-the-manif)

or even this:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace" />
```

Comment: I'm indeed using a few other packages. Perhaps the cause of the issue is the same, but these new permission settings can't seem to fix my problem.

Comment: What packages are you using?

Comment: I've got quite. a few dependencies. Please see update.

Comment: Try this: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it. They say on SDK >23, you have to request certain permissions i.e. ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},1);

Comment: I'm aware of that, but [this project](https://github.com/react-native-community/rncamera-example/) has `targetSdkVersion=26` and doesn't need to ask for the storage permissions at run-time to get the permissions though. Perhaps RN is meant to handle the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Appranetly SDK > 23 needs a require permission even if specified for certain things.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

```
private static final int PERMISSION_WRITE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

        Log.d("WritePermission", "No write permission given. Requesting...");
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PERMISSION_WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure native code for requesting permissions should be needed. [This project](https://github.com/react-native-community/rncamera-example/) gets the permissions without any native code for requesting permissions. They don't use `PermissionsAndroid` either.

Comment: Worth a try though?

Comment: I've fixed it now using `PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)` :)

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer.

Comment: No problem, just be sure to mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm only allowed to do it after 2 days though.